# Is there a way to use custom mangling in g++/clang++?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, name-mangling

When using c++ template, and especially tuples, I often get very long mangled names like

> _ZN11__sanitizer13InternalAllocEmPNS_28SizeClassAllocatorLocalCacheINS_20SizeClassAllocator32ILm0ELy140737488355328ELm0ENS_12SizeClassMapILm3ELm4ELm8ELm17ELm64ELm14EEELm20ENS_15TwoLevelByteMapILy32768ELy4096ENS_20NoOpMapUnmapCallbackEEES5_EEEEm

This is obviously fine in nominal case, and ease debugging but, when I use large tuples of custom types (with large namespaces) this ends up with very huge binaries just because of mangled names; Some tools (like valgrind) even have a symbol name maximum length that make analysis almost impossible.

I was wondering if there is a way to ask g++/clang++ to use a custom mangling function (say md5) so that the very long symbol becomes  `5c66b1073e1b453900bd7d32cb79fc0e` which is way shorter.

Answer (score 2):

The absence of this innovation in any important C++ implementation
is accounted for by the fact that a C++ compiler's name-mangling protocol is part of its [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)
and can't be the user's choice at the same time.

Notoriously, C++ code compiled with GCC is not interoperable with code compiled
with Microsoft compilers because, *inter alia*, they use different name-mangling
protocols. And the fact that they *do* use different name-mangling protocols,
and cannot be directed to use the same one, guarantees that subtler ABI
incompatibilities will not survive an attempted linkage.

The constancy of the C++ compiler's name-mangling protocol is also assumed in other toolchain utilities, e.g. binutils `nm`, `objdump`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to replace symbols entirely. But you can strip the binaries with `-s` to remove all symbols from it. This can reduce the size of your shipped binaries, but can of course not be used with debugging.

Comment: Actually I would like the compiler not to generate such big symbols as it may take a long time to write on file system things I would stip away later. BTW, choosing the mangling is not really about striping, IMHO